# Convert value from string to date format in SQL Server 2008

Tags: vb.net, string, sql-server-2008, date

I want to convert date which is stored as string in a SQL Server 2008 database to `smalldatetime`.

The format for the saved string is `16/12/2007` and I want to remove / and replace it with - to get proper date format which is `16-12-2007`

I getting the following error

> Conversion from string "16/12/2007" to type 'Date' is not valid.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "16/12/2007" to type 'Date' is not valid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 34:                 NewsItem.Visible = True
>   Line 35:                 NewsItem.Date_Modified = CDate(GetContent.Ndate)
>   Line 36:                 NewsItem.Date_Published = CDate(GetContent.Ndate)

I thought of creating a function that replace the `/` character with `-` to then update the database but it will take long time.

Comment: If you could avoid storing the dates as strings in the first place, the problem should never come up. SQL Server has perfectly usable `date` and `datetime2` data types, which ADO.NET knows how to translate to and from .NET `DateTime` types. You only encounter formatting issues if you deviate from this and use inappropriate storage types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the date as string from database and then  use Date.ParseExact which Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent.

```
Dim ydate = "16/12/2007"
Dim edate As Date = Date.ParseExact(ydate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use strings if you actually want to store `datetime`/`smalldatetime`s. Use sql-parameters to avoid localization/format issues and - more important - to prevent sql-injection. A VB.NET `Date` can be used for a `smalldatetime` column. Use `Date.TryParse` to validate and parse the string.

```
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.TableName(Date_Modified)VALUES(@Date_Modified);SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);"
Using con = New SqlConnection("Connection-String")
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        Dim dt As Date
        If Not Date.TryParse(GetContent.Ndate, dt) Then
            MessageBox.Show("please enter a valid date")
            Return
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Modified", dt)
        Dim newID = cmd.ExecuteScalar() ' presuming that you have an identity column that is autoincremented
    End Using
End Using
```